# Torque wrench not clicking

Tags: tools

My [torque wrench](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FMPKAD0) stopped clicking when it reached the torque set. Does that mean it needs to be recalibrated or it is broken for good?

The torque I was trying to set was pretty regular, something like 30-40 ft/lbs., regular hex bolts. It doesn't work with any torque within the tool's range and with any bolt. I found out the hard way, broke a bolt overtorquing it but I was way past the torque because the wrench didn't click.

Comment: To what measure are you torquing (lb-ft) to and what are you torquing (size of bolt or fastener)?

Comment: pretty regular torque, something like 30-40 ft/lbs.  regular hex bolts.  it doesn't work with any torque within the tool's range and with any bolt.  i found out the hard way, broke a bolt overtorquing it but i was way past the torque because the wrench didn't click

Comment: original updated

Answer (score 5):

Try this ... completely loosen the bolt you are trying to tighten. Use only the torque wrench to tighten it (never use a torque wench to loosen a fastener). See if you can get a click out of it that way. It could be the fastener is over tightened in the first place and it is clicking away without you noticing it at the beginning of the swing. If it still doesn't click, you'll need a new torque wrench. The ones you can purchase at Harbor Freight are a decent quality torque wrench for a cheap price (just throwing that out there).

Comment: I think I may have tried that but didn't work.  I'll try again tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick question for you.
Do you wind torque settings back to 0 when your not using the spanner?

If not the spring inside could be fatigued and will either need to be replaced and calibrated or probably cheaper to purchase a new torque spanner